# Run Firefox in headless mode using Protractor config

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor

I have this in my Protractor config:

```
  multiCapabilities: [

    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      firefoxOptions: {
        args: ['-headless']
      },
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['-headless']
      }
    }

  ]
```

unfortunately, when I launch Protractor, Firefox still runs in a headful mode. How to the heck do I tell Firefox to as headless?

I know that at the command line, the `-headless` option should work so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess, you are missing extra hypen (-) in your config.

```
multiCapabilities: [
{
  browserName: 'firefox',
  firefoxOptions: {
    args: ['--headless']
  },
  'moz:firefoxOptions': {
    args: [ '--headless' ]
  }
}
]
```

Also your browser version should be greater than 56.